# neo4j encountered error when attempting to reconcile database

Tags: neo4j, transition, reconcile

I am switching out 3.5.14 for 4.1.0, EE trial.  It's not really an upgrade; I deleted the databases directory altogether and csv imported my vertices and edges with neo4j-admin import.  The import ran fine, just as it has always done.  But upon starting the service, I get the following error in the debug.log file:

```
2020-07-01 18:12:54.517+0000 WARN [c.n.d.DbmsReconciler] Reconciler triggered but the following databases are currently failed and may be ignored: [neo4j]. Run `SHOW DATABASES` for further information.
2020-07-01 18:12:54.518+0000 INFO [c.n.d.DbmsReconciler] Database neo4j is requested to transition from EnterpriseDatabaseState{databaseId=DatabaseId{b1fac61d[neo4j]}, operatorState=STOPPED, failed=true} to EnterpriseDatabaseState{databaseId=DatabaseId{b1fac61d[neo4j]}, operatorState=STARTED, failed=false}
2020-07-01 18:12:54.518+0000 ERROR [c.n.d.DbmsReconciler] Encountered error when attempting to reconcile database neo4j from state 'EnterpriseDatabaseState{databaseId=DatabaseId{b1fac61d[neo4j]}, operatorState=STOPPED, failed=true}' to state 'online' An error occurred! Unable to start database with name `neo4j`.
```

That happens after it successfully creates the "system" db.

Order of events:

```
yum install of 4.1.0 per instructions.
Change out of neo4j.conf with new version, updated to the connectors for my single instance system.
Created the neo4j admin password.
Removed the contents of the old versions of the epoc jar files from the plugins directory.
Imported the data
Started the database getting the error.  Otherwise the web portal is accessible, though the neo4j db is not.
```

What can be done differently to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you only have to uncomment this line in neo4j.conf, as the database needs to upgrade from the 3.x version to 4.x.

```
dbms.allow_upgrade=true
```

Comment: I had tried that before and didn't get anything.  I was wondering why I would need that as I wasn't really upgrading the data as I was starting my database from scratch.  Nevertheless, this time I made sure that, in addition to the databases directory, that I deleted the dumps and transactions directories also.  It came right up.  I then changed the config file to put the comment back in.  And started the service again.  And it is still ok.  It's hard to tell what all was needed.  Thank you!